# play sbt dist command stuck

Tags: java, scala, playframework, sbt

Last week (2018/04/18) I've generated a distribution pack of my project. From yesterday (2018/04/23) sbt dist command does not finish and give me no errors.

I tried the source from last week and tried running it on Windows and Linux but the behaviour is the same.

Checkout the sbt log below:

```
    C:\Beto\Hg\mobilecontrolweb>.\sbt-dist\bin\sbt.bat
    Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
    [info] Loading settings from plugins.sbt,sbt-ui.sbt ...
    [info] Loading project definition from C:\Beto\Hg\mobilecontrolweb\project
    [debug] Full compilation, no sources in previous analysis.
    [debug] Copy resource mappings:
    [debug]
    [info] Loading settings from build.sbt ...
    [info] Set current project to CcmPlayApp (in build file:/C:/Beto/Hg/mobilecontrolweb/)
    [info] sbt server started at local:sbt-server-fa35b33dfcba0f6d759f
    [CcmPlayApp] $ clean
    [success] Total time: 3 s, completed 24/04/2018 15:19:04
    [CcmPlayApp] $ dist
    [info] Updating ...
    [info] Packaging C:\Beto\Hg\mobilecontrolweb\target\scala-2.11\ccmplayapp_2.11-1.0-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar ...
    [info] Done packaging.
    [info] Done updating.
    [warn] Found version conflict(s) in library dependencies; some are suspected to be binary incompatible:
    [warn]  * com.google.guava:guava:22.0 is selected over {19.0, 15.0, 20.0}
    [warn]      +- com.jolbox:bonecp:0.8.0.RELEASE                    (depends on 15.0)
    [warn]      +- org.reflections:reflections:0.9.11                 (depends on 15.0)
    [warn]      +- com.typesafe.play:play_2.11:2.6.11                 (depends on 15.0)
    [warn]      +- com.google.inject:guice:4.1.0                      (depends on 19.0)
    [warn]  * org.scala-lang.modules:scala-java8-compat_2.11:0.8.0 is selected over 0.7.0
    [warn]      +- com.typesafe.play:play-java-forms_2.11:2.6.11      (depends on 0.8.0)
    [warn]      +- com.typesafe.play:play-java_2.11:2.6.11            (depends on 0.8.0)
    [warn]      +- com.typesafe.play:play_2.11:2.6.11                 (depends on 0.7.0)
    [warn]      +- com.typesafe.akka:akka-actor_2.11:2.5.8 ()         (depends on 0.7.0)
    [warn]      +- com.typesafe.play:play-streams_2.11:2.6.11         (depends on 0.7.0)
    [warn]  * com.typesafe.akka:akka-stream_2.11:2.5.8 is selected over 2.4.20
    [warn]      +- com.typesafe.play:play-streams_2.11:2.6.11         (depends on 2.5.8)
    [warn]      +- com.typesafe.akka:akka-http-core_2.11:10.0.11 ()   (depends on 2.4.20)
    [warn]  * com.typesafe.akka:akka-actor_2.11:2.5.8 is selected over 2.4.20
    [warn]      +- com.typesafe.akka:akka-slf4j_2.11:2.5.8 ()         (depends on 2.5.8)
    [warn]      +- com.typesafe.play:play_2.11:2.6.11                 (depends on 2.5.8)
    [warn]      +- com.typesafe.akka:akka-stream_2.11:2.5.8 ()        (depends on 2.5.8)
    [warn]      +- com.typesafe.akka:akka-parsing_2.11:10.0.11 ()     (depends on 2.4.20)
    [warn] Run 'evicted' to see detailed eviction warnings
    [info] Wrote C:\Beto\Hg\mobilecontrolweb\target\scala-2.11\ccmplayapp_2.11-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
    [info] Main Scala API documentation to C:\Beto\Hg\mobilecontrolweb\target\scala-2.11\api...
    [info] Packaging C:\Beto\Hg\mobilecontrolweb\target\scala-2.11\ccmplayapp_2.11-1.0-SNAPSHOT-web-assets.jar ...
    [info] Done packaging.
    [info] Compiling 186 Scala sources and 170 Java sources to C:\Beto\Hg\mobilecontrolweb\target\scala-2.11\classes ...
    [warn] there was one feature warning; re-run with -feature for details
    model contains 524 documentable templates
    [warn] one warning found
    [info] Main Scala API documentation successful.
    [info] Packaging C:\Beto\Hg\mobilecontrolweb\target\scala-2.11\ccmplayapp_2.11-1.0-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar ...
    [info] Done packaging.
    [warn] there was one feature warning; re-run with -feature for details
    [warn] one warning found
    [info] C:\Beto\Hg\mobilecontrolweb\app\controllers\ContractController.java: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
    [info] C:\Beto\Hg\mobilecontrolweb\app\controllers\ContractController.java: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
    [info] Done compiling.
```

Comment: Please explain what would happen upon succesful execution. What happens after the last line that says Done compiling?

Comment: in sbt you can try to put the logs in debug mode with the command `debug` (and use `info` to get back to normal behaviour). This may help to pinpoint the issue

Comment: Thomas, nothing happened after the last line (Done compiling), no prompt. What I expected to happen was the zip file with distribution package was generated.

 vdebergue, I put on debug mode. Thank ou for the tip. But no helpfull information.

We, finally, solved the problem changing the plugins.sbt file
from:
addSbtPlugin(“com.typesafe.sbteclipse” % “sbteclipse-plugin” % “5.2.1”)

to:
addSbtPlugin(“com.typesafe.sbteclipse” % “sbteclipse-plugin” % “5.2.4”)
(thank you Leo!)
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "5.2.1") inside plugins.sbt; It seems like using this version instead of 5.2.4, when sbt version is above 0.13, makes run and dist stuck without any log whatsoever.